# How does this page call the action on button click

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

On this page, http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

The screenshot button is generating a screenshot of the page supplied on the text box.

I tried to view the source of the page and inspect element but I can't find how the function to generate the screenshot was made. There is no onclick made on the button.

I'd like to do something similar using his html2canvass js but instead of appending it to the bottom of the page, I want to save as jpeg the supplied website url.

Anyone has and Idea how this can be done? I am assuming that onclick would do but I don't get the part that call the function to generate the screenshot.

I'd like to dynamically generate an image version of my html lyrics so that user can have an option to view my lyrics on html or save it as jpeg.

sample lyrics: http://prompter.rareapps.org/prompt/prompt-save.php?p=123

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the element from js to add an onclick event:

Your button (or link, or div or what ever):

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" id="button" />
```

Native javascript:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick=function () {
   // Do your magic here
};
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
   // Do your magic
});
```

You can also access the object by class, or by its parent or by its content, not just id.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/N8j8p/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok. I get the part you mentioned so far. But on the on the page I mentioned above, it is vague how the url on the text field was supplied as an argument to to the onclick action to generate the screenshot. There was no onclick on the page.

Comment: Well, why must it be an argument? In the function above you can grep the content of the text field and call the function that generates the image with that as argument.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/N8j8p/1/

Comment: I think I am short of english. I can't explain what I am trying to say. If you can perhaps view this view-source:http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html you might get what I am trying to say. Your example I can grasp because I can see you have variables declared, you have id's on the code that connect each other. On that page however, there is almost nothing that make sense but still it is functioning like it was coded like your jsfiddle samples.

Comment: They also has id's. The button has id 'getscreenshot' and the textfield has id 'url'. The script how ever is here: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/site/console.js?_=1395426191767 See line 71 for example.

Comment: WOW! How did you get that? When I inspect element and view source I can't see those codes. Where is it located?

Comment: They use a lot of magic stuff as you can see in source. AngularJS for example. Just look in you browser development tools and look witch JS files is fetched.

Comment: Lots of magic indeed. They seem to have chunks of the site elsewhere and put it together on that page. way beyond my league. Thanks a lot. for the conversation and great help.